# JQuery on click function, except one?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm using javascript to display a notification when a user clicks on an  tag (Are you sure you want to leave this page?) but I don't want it to work on the one that posts the form. Is there any way of making it work for all  tags except one?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('a').on('click', function()
    {
        var note=$("#formnote").val();
        if (note.length > 0){
            var redirectquestion = confirm("Are you sure that you want to leave this page?");
            if(!redirectquestion ){
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I suggest looking up the jQuery selector documentation. There are multiple solutions to this.

Comment: `$('a:not(.submits_form)').on('click'...`

Comment: Please add your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work if I understand te question right (and assuming you add the class `submitLink` to the tag you don't want to trigger this call from

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('a:not(.submitLink)').on('click', function()
  {
    var note=$("#formnote").val();
    if (note.length > 0){
      var redirectquestion = confirm("Are you sure that you want to leave this page?");
      if(!redirectquestion ){
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a:not(#link_submit)").on('click', function () {
        var note = $("#formnote").val();
        if (note.length > 0) {
            var redirectquestion = confirm("Are you sure that you want to leave this page?");
            if (!redirectquestion) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery's [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) so that you're not binding an event handler to that element and using resources to not do anything. Also, you can easily assign a click handler to that element later without worrying about your previous code. So something like this:

```
$('a').not('.submitLink').on('click', function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**With not selector :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a:not(#link_submit)').on('click', function () {
    var note = $("#formnote").val();
        if (note.length > 0) {
            var redirectquestion = confirm("Are you sure that you want to leave this page?");
            if (!redirectquestion) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**With .not() :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a').not('#link_submit').on('click', function () {
    var note = $("#formnote").val();
        if (note.length > 0) {
            var redirectquestion = confirm("Are you sure that you want to leave this page?");
            if (!redirectquestion) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

This should work also - if your a-tag has the id 'submit'.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').not('#submit').on('click', function () {
        var note = $("#formnote").val();
        if (note.length > 0) {
            var redirectquestion = confirm("Are you sure that you want to leave this page?");
            if (!redirectquestion) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```